# How do I apply grayscale to my image with SimpleFilters in C#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, imageresizer

I am creating a function in Azure that takes an image and resizes it + makes it grayscale. I'm currently using this function:

```
#r "System.Drawing"

using ImageResizer;
using ImageResizer.Plugins.SimpleFilters;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

public static void Run(Stream inputImage, string imageName, Stream 
resizedImage, TraceWriter log)
{
  log.Info($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{imageName} \n 
  Size: {inputImage.Length} Bytes");

  var settings = new ImageResizer.ResizeSettings{
    MaxWidth = 400,
    Format = "png"
  };

  // Add the grayscale filter to the image
  inputImage.filters.Add(GrayscaleNTSC());

  ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Current.Build(inputImage, resizedImage, settings);

}
```

I'm importing the Plugins.SimpleFilters but I don't know how to use it in C#. The project site provides examples in pure HTML.

Do you know how to grayscale the image?

I get the following error:
The name 'GrayscaleNTSC' does not exist in the current context

The packages I'm using are:

```
"dependencies": {
  "ImageResizer": "4.0.5",
  "ImageResizer.Plugins.SimpleFilters": "4.0.5"
}
```

Comment: So what is GrayscaleNTSC? You are trying to call it as if it's your static method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I assume that you could leverage Managed API from ImageResizer to achieve your purpose. Here is my test, you could refer to it:

**Core code**

```
//install the SimpleFilters plugin
ImageResizer.Configuration.Config.Current.Plugins.Install(new SimpleFilters());
var settings = new ResizeSettings("width=400&height=500&crop=auto&s.grayscale=true");
ImageBuilder.Current.Build($"{baseDir}/resources/image_01.jpg", $"{baseDir}/resources/image_01_01.jpg",
                    settings);
```

**Result**

- Orignal image: https://z.zr.io/ri/utah2.jpg
- Modified image:

[image]

Additionally, you could refer to [Managed API samples](https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/managed) and [SimpleFilters plugin](https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/simplefilters) for more details.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed. I had trouble finding that documentation. It now works as it should.